# Check for a hashtag (#) within a line. Python 2.7

Tags: python, search, lines, hashtag

I need to search each line within a text file for a hash (#). I am using Python 2.7.

I have already implemented the cycle through each line, and can find other expressions but for some reason the code isn't recognising a '#' in any line.

Things I have tried:

`if re.search(r'(?=.#.)',lines[b]):`

`if "#" in line:`

`if '\#' in line:`

(line or lines[b] corresponds to the line which my for loop is currently looking at)

The text I am searching is made up of blocks which contains lines like:

> L_EXPO #(

Any other ideas?

Comment: Then maybe you aren't parsing your lines properly? What happens if you `print(line)`? Can you come back with a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I tried using `if "#" in line:` it works fine for me.

Comment: I think @AndrewGuy you might be right. I've just tried separating that small section off and it seems to then find the #. Thank you!